# IF condition in SQL query in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have Oracle sql query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE 1 =1
AND req_no IN
  (SELECT req_no
  FROM test
  WHERE date1 IS NOT NULL
  AND date1 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12'
  )
```

The problem is that the `WHERE` condition doesn't work properly. In above condition if 'date1'
is NOT NULL then I want to check 'date1' in between 'FROM' and 'TO' date.
****EDIT****
I have added sample table data

```
Test table
From date: 1-JUN-2012
To date: 30-JUN-2012

record      date1          date2            date3
1       12-JUN-2012     13-JUN-2012         12-JUN-2012
2       null            null                12-JUN-2012
3       null            3-JUN-2012          null
4       12-JUN-2012     null                null
5       12-JUN-2012     13-JUL-2012         12-JUN-2012
6       null                null             null
```

In the above record it will return  record number=1,2,3,4 not 6th record.

Comment: THis code is not an example of best practice but it ought to solve the business rule you give.  So you need to define "doesn't work properly".  The easiest way is to give us some test data and teh output you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have added sample data and output

Comment: @APC: I have sample table data and output

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you should **not** rely on implicit data type conversion as you do with the dates. It might fail if the NLS settings are changed. Use `to_date()` or an ANSI date literal: `DATE '2012-06-01'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` like this:

```
WHERE date1 IS NULL
  OR date1 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12'
```

Your whole query should be:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE 1 =1
AND req_no IN
  (SELECT req_no
  FROM test
  WHERE date1 IS NULL
  OR date1 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12'
  )
```

Comment: @Raje From your question **if 'date1' is NOT NULL then I want to check 'date1' in between 'FROM' and 'TO' date.** That means if Date is `NULL` you don't want to check between. Right?

Comment: @Raje Then the condition in the above query is same as you want. Isn't it?

Comment: In your condition it will return record which has null value i. e 6th record in this example

Answer (score 0):

The `1=1` is redundant. Since you said you wanted to check if date1 is between the range of date OR if it's null it is also okay, Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE req_no IN
  (SELECT req_no
  FROM test
  WHERE date1 BETWEEN to_date('06/01/2012','mm/dd/yyyy') 
         AND to_date('06/30/2012','mm/dd/yyyy') 
        OR date1 is null
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont need subquery you can directly select your relevant record using single query
like also you dont need to check `date1` is null or not

```
SELECT *  FROM test
  WHERE TO_DATE('12/2/2003','MM/DD/YYYY') <= date1 
AND TO_DATE('12/5/2003','MM/DD/YYYY') >= date1
```

Answer (score 0):

Found some workaround but it is very lengthy

```
  SELECT *
FROM dates
WHERE 1  =1
AND( 
  no IN
  ( SELECT no FROM dates WHERE date1 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12'
  and date2 is null and date3 is null ) 
  or 
   no IN
  ( SELECT no FROM dates WHERE date2 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12'
  and date1 is null and date3 is null ) 
  or 
   no IN
  ( SELECT no FROM dates WHERE date3 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12'
  and date1 is null and date2 is null ) 
   or 
   no IN
  ( SELECT no FROM dates WHERE date3 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12'
  and date1 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12' and date2 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12' )
   or 
   no IN
  ( SELECT no FROM dates WHERE date1 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12'
  and date1 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12' and date3 is null )
    or 
   no IN
  ( SELECT no FROM dates WHERE date3 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12'
  and date3 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12' and date2 is null )
   or 
   no IN
  ( SELECT no FROM dates WHERE date2 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12'
  and date3 BETWEEN '1-JUN-12' AND '30-JUN-12' and date1 is null )

  )
```

Comment: Ah - but this was not how you stated the problem initially.  In your initial description you were only checking `date1`.  If you fail to describe the problem completely you're not going to get much in the way of useful answers.  As it is you've got seven SELECT conditions for six rows - seems a bit like overkill to me.